# Using ACF's Link custom field in Timber Menu

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I need to add custom CTA links to a site's main menu. Currently, my menu markup is this:

```
<nav id="js-menu--primary" class="menu menu--primary clearfix" aria-label="{{ site_nav.title|e}} Menu" role="navigation">
  <button id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle" aria-label={{ __('Menu', 'realease')|e('esc_html') }} aria-expanded="false">
  <span></span>
</button>
<ul class="menu__items menu__items--primary clearfix">
{% for item in site_nav.items %}
  <li class="{{ item.classes|join(' ') }} menu__item">
    <a class="menu__link menu__link--primary" href="{{ item.link }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
    {% if item.children %}
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        {% for child in item.children %}
          <li class="sub-menu__item">
            <a href="{{ child.link }}">{{ child.title }}</a>
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</nav><!-- .menu--primary -->
```

I would like to add the CTA link after the menu items, which would render as:

```
  <li class="site__header--cta">
    <a href="ctalink" class="button button__secondary">ctatext</a>
  </li>
```

How can I include these ACF menu link fields in my twig template?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the link is hardcoded and visible always no matter what then only thing you need to do is to add it after the `{% endfor %}` tag.

Then it would read like:

```
<nav id="js-menu--primary" class="menu menu--primary clearfix" aria-label="{{ site_nav.title|e}} Menu" role="navigation">
  <button id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle" aria-label={{ __('Menu', 'realease')|e('esc_html') }} aria-expanded="false">
  <span></span>
</button>
<ul class="menu__items menu__items--primary clearfix">
{% for item in site_nav.items %}
  <li class="{{ item.classes|join(' ') }} menu__item">
    <a class="menu__link menu__link--primary" href="{{ item.link }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
    {% if item.children %}
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        {% for child in item.children %}
          <li class="sub-menu__item">
            <a href="{{ child.link }}">{{ child.title }}</a>
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
  <li class="site__header--cta">
    <a href="ctalink" class="button button__secondary">ctatext</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav><!-- .menu--primary -->
```

However if you want to do it dynamically for navigation items and pull that information from wordpress menu's then I would need to have more information about your setup in order to help you.